# R: plotting a function, but "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"

Tags: r, function, plot

I have witten this simple function in R

```
> w=c(0.005,0.005,0.006,0.01,0.88,0.03,0.01,0.01,0.005,0.34,0.05)  
> trial<- function(a) {sum(a-w)}  
> trial(0.1)  
[1] 0.996
```

As you can see this function works fine if I put in a value for a, however I want to plot it and unlike a function not involving sum, the following does not work:

```
> plot(trial)
```

Giving me the error:

```
> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :  
  'x' and 'y' lengths differ  
In addition: Warning message:  
In a - w : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I understand that R is asking for a vector of length 11, but is there a way to plot this function?

Comment: There is probably a better way around this but you might want to look into `Vectorize`

Comment: What exactly do you expect to plot?  Your function will always return a single value...

Comment: Are you trying to do something like `x <- 1:10; plot(x,trial(x))`?

Comment: @Justin. When plot is used on a function not involving "sum" e.g trial<- function(x) {x^2}, it will plot the x^2 curve on the domain (0,1)

Comment: That is correct.  Maybe you want something like: `x=as.list(1:10); plot(x, sapply(x, trial))`

Comment: @Justin Thanks, this seems to work, I replaced 1:10 by 1:10000/10000 to make it more continuous, but is there a way to make it truly continuous (in the same way that plot(trial) would be if trial<- function(x) {x^2})

Comment: @user1958688 Your `plot(trial)` isn't as continuous as you think. `x^2` is very smooth, but only 101 points are plotted (with lines between them). That's the default for `curve`, which `plot` uses as indicated in `?plot.function`.

Comment: Sorry that my question didn't have much clarity. Justin's method works. My function above takes a single value a, say a=0.5, then it calculates the sum (0.5-0.005)+(0.5-0.005)+(0.5-0.006)+(0.5-0.01)+...   i.e. I guess it turn my single input into a vector of 11 indentical elements. I just wanted to be able to plot this function on the domain (0,1)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem lies within your function and what you expect it to give you, and what you have coded.

`sum(a-w)` will return a single number.

So when you pass a vector (as the `plot.function`  method and underlying `curve` function will do, it creates a sequence `seq(0,1,n=101)` (by default).

now your function creates `a-w` before summing it. Therefore it really only makes sense if is a single value or a vector of the same length as `w`

```
trial(seq(0,1,length.out = 101))
[1] 38.331
Warning message:
In x - w : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

It gives an answer, but a warning that you have tried to do something that is perhaps foolish.

The error comes from the fact that when R creates the plot it is creating

```
plot(seq(0,1,length.out = 101), trial(seq(0,1,length.out = 101))
```

which will give you the  error.

```
 Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
 'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

So, the question is what do you want your function to return when given  vector for `a`

should it be `a- sum(w)`? in which case you should really redefine your function to reflect what you want

```
trial2 <- function(a) {a - sum(w)}
```

and then

```
plot(trial2)
```

will give you a nice (if somewhat uninteresting) straight line

[image]

Until you redefine `w`

```
w <- 'something else'

plot(trial2)
Error in sum(w) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

Which is the problem with relying on global variables wthin a function.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this is what you wanted:

```
trial<- function(x) {cumsum(x)}
plot(seq_along(w),  trial(w), type="l")
```

[image]
Although it's just a guess. If this is correct (and even if it's not exactly what you wanted)  then there are two lessons. 1) Describe the problem fully in natural language; 2) Use functions that return vectors. I think that the `cumsum` and `cumprod` functions might not get prominent display in introductory texts. And with them in that situation are also `pmin` and `pmax` that are often needed when new users are failing in efforts with max and min.

Also possible this is what you expected:

```
trial<- function(x) {cumsum(x-w)}
  plot(seq_along(w),  trial(0.1), type="l")
```

A much more jagged plot results. If smoothness is needed search on `smooth.spline`.